# PLCameraController is not adding in viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've declared PLCameraContoller instance in my AppDelegate class as:-

```
self.cameraController = [PLCameraController performSelector:@selector(sharedInstance)];
[cameraController setDelegate:self];
```

And I'm accessing it in one of my viewcontroller class as:-

```
del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *previewView = [del.cameraController performSelector:@selector(previewView)];
previewView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480);
self.view = previewView;
[del.cameraController performSelector:@selector(startPreview)];
[del.cameraController performSelector:@selector(setCameraMode:) withObject:(NSNumber*)1];
```

Where "del" is an instance of my AppDelegate class.

But i can see only black background in my viewcontroller view in iphone device.

Also if i remove "self" from the appdelegate.m code of cameracontroller it also showing blank.

How can i get camera in my view controller?
I'm pretty much struggling with it.

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to retain the PLCameraController instance. Did you declare the cameraController with the retain attribute? If not, you'll need to retain it manually.

```
[cameraController retain];
```